# passing a paperclip image from the controller to a view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, instance-variables

I have a model that has an image attached to it that I want to be passed through a controller into a view. This is the way I have tried myself but it does not work:

Model:

```
class CustomForm < ActiveRecord:Base
    has_attached_file :background_image,
      :storage => :s3,
      :bucket => "asdf",
      ...

    belongs_to  :project
```

Controller:

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :get_project

    def show
        @form = @project.forms.find(params[:id])
        @bg_image = @form.background_image.url
    end

    def get_project
        @project = current_account.projects.find(params[:project_id])
    end
```

View:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <%= image_tag @bg_image %>
    </body>
</html>
```

This creates a "can't convert nil into String" error and points to the "<%= image_tag @bg_image %>" line, and I assume @bg_image is nil. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `@project` being properly set? If so, is `@form.background_image` nil or does it have a value?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is because the @form variable is working fine

Comment: Hmm, well I'm curious as to why `@bg_image` wasn't working but `@form.background_image.url` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uou might need to eval the image_tag line:

```
<%= eval("image_tag #{@bg_image}")
```

Since you aren't saving anything by having @bg_image set in the controller, you can just as easily do. :

```
<%= image_tag @form.background_image.url %>
```

Which will probably render a nano-second faster and it looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: doing <%= image_tag "#{@bg_image}" %> kind of worked but the image is undefined

Comment: That won't work, because it'll just be a text object, which is why you need to put it within an eval.

Comment: But why even do this? Just use the second option?

Comment: There is no reason to use `eval`. If the object is nil, it doesn't matter how the method is invoked; it will still fail.

Comment: Yeah, the second option works. I just don't get why the way I was doing it, @bg_image was nil

Comment: If I could I would still like to use the instance variable because I have some more logic I need to perform on it in the controller

Comment: Probably if you outputted @bg_image it would show the url, not nil. The nil is coming out as a result of being evaluated by 'image_tag', which is why you can solve it by using eval, which will first process the #{bg_image} before 'image_tag'.

Comment: What more do you want to do with it? Generally, you have to use eval if you want to do a lot more logic..

Comment: well I have more images in my model and I was hoping to join them in an array in the controller like this: "@images = [@form.image1.url, @form.image2.url, @form.image3.url]" as well as some other tiny stuff